# What is the purpose of ROS_WORKSPACE

Tags: ros, roscd, ros-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently installed Fuerte and now when I run roscd without arguments it complains that ROS_WORKSPACE is not set. I haven't been able to find much information about this new environment variable. So far, I can only see that roscd uses it.

Is this just used by roscd or are there other tools that use it? And is it something that I need to set?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34914/what-is-the-purpose-of-ros_workspace/) by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 544 on 2012-05-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS_WORKSPACE is set by the setup.sh created by rosinstall or rosws. it points to the path in which the setup.sh and the .rosinstall are located.

It is used by rosinstall / rosws, and also by roscd. No other tool uses it as far as I know.

If roscd without arguments complains that it is missing, then don't call roscd without arguments.

In electric and earlier, roscd without arguments would go to ROS_ROOT. However, starting with fuerte (and catkin), ROS_ROOT becomes less important (and should eventually go away), so we had the choice of making roscd without arguments do nothing, or do something useful sometimes.

If that were too confusing we could change roscd to not complain if no ROS_WORKSPACE is set and do nothing instead.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS_WORKSPACE is the path to the folder where you put all the packages you make yourself. Sometimes also for extra packages you want to install. You should check out the tutorials on ros.org.

---

Originally posted by [Kat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1982/kat/) with karma: 155 on 2012-05-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) on 2012-05-26**:
The tutorial mentions it being used by roscd. There is no other program in /opt/ros/fuerte that uses it. But I saw that rosinstall adds it to the setup script it creates. Another tool that uses it is rosws, which comes with rosinstall.

**Comment by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) on 2012-05-26**:
@Hordur I believe it's only used by `roscd`. It's the default directory you switch to if you run `roscd` with no parameters.